# How to delete blanks and some symbols from a array

Tags: xamarin.android

How to delete blanks and some symbols from a array

//
12 33 3 => 12333 14-546_9 => 145469

```
SparseArray items = detections.DetectedItems;
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); ++i)
                    {
                       strBuilder.Append(((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value);
                        strBuilder.Append("\n");
                    }
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Extract data from ocr
, And I want to delete each line containing a space or symbol " - " or " , " or  " _ "  or dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Regex** to extract numbers,like:

```
string s = "14-546_9 ";
string regEx = "[^0-9]";
Java.Util.Regex.Pattern p = Java.Util.Regex.Pattern.Compile(regEx);
Matcher m = p.Matcher(s);
string result = m.ReplaceAll("").Trim();
```